# 数時間経過するとMySQLに接続できなくなる。（Lost connection to MySQL server during queryが発生する。）

Tags: python, python3, mysql, django

Djangoで、デフォルトのSqlite3データベースから、MySQLに置き換えました。
MySQLへの接続はできたのですが、数時間放置すると、以下のエラーが発生するようになりました。
どのようにすれば、このエラーを解消できるか、教えていただけないでしょうか。

Web検索したところ似たような事象が再現しているようで、関連する記事はあるのですが、
いろいろな解決方法が記載されており、どの解決方法が当てはまるのか読み取ることができませんでした。
（私の基礎知識が不足しており、理解できませんでした。）
https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/asgi-mysql-server-has-gone-away-and-conn-max-age/5240/7
https://www.ytyng.com/blog/mysql-django-no-engine-substitution/

- 構成
  nginx ⇒ gunicorn ⇒ flask ⇒ DjangoのORM ⇒ MySQL
  nginx、flask(+Django)、MySQLをそれぞれDockerコンテナ化しています。
  flask(+Django)のコンテナを再起動すると、MySQLへの接続が復旧します。
- Djangoのデータベース接続設定
  以下の設定で、MySQLデータベースへ接続しています。（DjangoのORM機能のみ利用しています。）

```
database = {}
database['default'] = {  # MySQL
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE'],
    'USER': os.environ['MYSQL_USER'],
    'PASSWORD': os.environ['MYSQL_PASSWORD'],
    'HOST': os.environ.get('MYSQL_HOST', '127.0.0.1')
    'PORT': '3306',
}
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(  # 一度のみ設定可能
    DATABASES=database,
    INSTALLED_APPS=[AppConfig(app_name='orcas', app_module=importlib.import_module('orcas'))],
    LANGUAGE_CODE='ja',
    TIME_ZONE='Asia/Tokyo',
    USE_I18N=True,
    USE_TZ=True,
)
```

- Gunicornの設定
  Dockerfileより以下のコマンドでGunicornを起動しています。

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--workers", "4", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "src.gpts:app"]
```

- エラーログ
  以下、MySQLに接続できなくなったときのエラーログです。

```
[2024-02-06 23:15:06 JST] <INFO> [orcas.utils.process]_query(gpts.py:183) - Total:[15.61]GiB, Memory:[??        ], CPU:[          ] - SQL:[select * from orcas_jp_news order by date desc limit 10;]
[2024-02-06 23:15:06 JST] <ERROR> [orcas]_query(gpts.py:188) - (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 179, in execute
    res = self._query(mogrified_query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 330, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/workspace/orcas_proj/flask_proj/src/gpts.py", line 186, in _query
    result = app_models.execute_query(sql=sql, output_format='dict')
  File "/var/workspace/orcas_proj/jupyter_proj/orcas/models/models.py", line 924, in execute_query
    cursor.execute(sql=sql, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 179, in execute
    res = self._query(mogrified_query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 330, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

当件、原因が突き止められず、あきらめました。
以下のように、DjangoのORMではなく、
他のMySQL用ライブラリィを利用することで、
当問題（長時間経過すると接続できなくなる問題の発生）を回避しました。
一旦クローズとします。

```
import MySQLdb

# DjangoのDB接続では、長時間経過すると接続が切れるため、mysqlclientで毎回独自に接続する
db_settings = {
    'user': os.environ.get('MYSQL_READ_ONLY_USER', 'XXXX'),  # MySQLのユーザー名
    'passwd': os.environ.get('MYSQL_READ_ONLY_PASSWORD', 'XXXX'),  # MySQLのパスワード
    'db': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'orcas'),  # 接続したいデータベース名
    'host': os.environ.get('MYSQL_HOST', '127.0.0.1')  # データベースサーバーのホスト名
}

db = MySQLdb.connect(**db_settings)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
column_list = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]  # カラム名を取得
result = [dict(zip(column_list, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```